# AngularJS CSS Animations Not Working

Tags: angularjs, css, css-animations

I can't get animations to work for ng-show only.

This works to fade out and fade in:

```
        .animate-show {
            display: block !important;
            -webkit-transition:all linear 1.5s;
            transition:all linear 1.5s;
        }

        .animate-show.ng-hide {
            opacity:0;
        }

    <div ng-show="match.userId" style="margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto;" class="padding animate-show ng-hide">
      ...
    </div>
```

I want to fade IN only.... no animation on hide. This doesn't work

```
       .animate-show {
            display: block !important;
        }

        .animate-show.ng-hide-remove.ng-hide-remove-active {
            -webkit-transition:all linear 1.5s;
            transition:all linear 1.5s;
        }

        .animate-show.ng-hide {
            opacity:0;
        }
```

Here's a plunkr:

```
http://plnkr.co/edit/9KNqt5TAZ8Ejy8eeJUQs
```

Comment: can you post a plunkr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.animate-show.ng-hide-remove.ng-hide-remove-active {
```

`ng-hide-remove-active` is too late, you only need `ng-hide-remove`.

[Working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/iTy7BeNsFOQm76fZhCZa?p=preview)

Comment: No impact, see plunkr.

Comment: Your example only works for Angular 1.3.0RC. I'm using Ionic framework which seems to only support 1.2.4.

Comment: @Jeff There were some bugs that have been fixed with 1.2.17. You could always switch to JavaScript based animations though.

Comment: in my case, it seems ng-hide-remove-active makes the whole animation to stop working, I removed it as you advised, and it started working. However, this: ng-hide-remove-active was from angular docs so I'm not sure why would this still work.